# Multiple definition exception in C++

Tags: c++

I am starting to learn C++ and am getting this compilation error from my IDE (CodeBlocks). I don't understand why this is happening.

```
|2|multiple definition of `parser::parseFile()'
|2|first defined here|
```

I don't see how this could happen. This is my entire code base.

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include "parser/parser.cpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

#### `parser/parser.cpp`

```
namespace parser {
    void parseFile() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't include .cpp files, you link to them. Go to `Project->Add->New Class` then it will create a .h file and .cpp file. Put the declaration in the .h file, definition in the .cpp fine and include the header file instead.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well, technically you can't link to a cpp file, but you can include it, although one probably shouldn't. Moreover, as it is presented now, the code should compile. The error is somewhere else. Probably the file is included two times.

Comment: @luk32 I don't think the code should compile in its present form - parser.cpp will be compiled, containing the `parseFile` definition, and so will main.cpp, also containing the `parseFile` definition. Hence the error.

Comment: No. It would break on linking then. It is not compiling. Try copy pasting the contents of `parser.cpp` into main instead of include and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you compiled both `main.cpp` and `parser/parse.cpp` you clearly have two definitions of `parser::parseFile()`: the `#include` directive just become replaced by the content of the named file (you can use the `-E` flag with your compiler to see the result).

You probably meant to *declare* `parser::parseFile()` in a *header file* (typically with a suffix `.h` or `.hpp` or something like that):

```
// file: parser/parser.hpp
#ifndef INCLUDED_PARSER_PARSER
#define INCLUDED_PARSER_PARSER

namespace parser {
    void parseFile();
}

#endif
```

... and to include this header file into *both* translation units.

Comment: If this is cpp i'd recommend `#pragma once`. I've heard that there are practical reasons on some compilers, as they cache the name of file, and don't even try to open it 2nd time, while with the guard, they need to, unless they are smart enough to figure out there is such a guard. Also some other evil file might undefine the guard.

Comment: @luk32: I do not recommend compiler-specific facilities. Since I need to compile my code across platforms, I prefer it to be portable. Also, all decent compiler detect the include guards and won't touch the files, either: necessity of `#pragma once` is certainly false information. It may be _nice_ to have something as simple as `#pragma once` but I'd rather have [modules](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) instead of standardizing something akin to `#pragma once`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl we use #pragma once without issue with gcc and clang. I'm not sure what vc++ does with it though.

Comment: @James: I need to compile my code, at least, with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), Oracle's [CC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/features/compilers-2332272.html), and IBM's [xlC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_XL_C%2B%2B). The latter two do not support `#pragma once` as far as I know. The include guards happen to be supported by all four compilers.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Fair enough, of course. I'd still prefer it if was supported. It's just a better alternative to me, worth of noting. I prefer encapsulation instead of (silent) code contracts. You can't undefine it for whatever reason. And you won't get name clash, which might be unlikely but is possible. I saw it once.

Answer (score 1):

Your program have violated the [One Definition Rule (also known as ODR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).
In short, `parser::parseFile` function have been defined in both of your `.cpp` files, because on the compiler level, `#include <header.h>` simply means substituting the entire file contents in place.
Solution to your problem depends on your actual program, though. If you want to solve the ODR rule for class definitions, you can do either of:

1) Add a `#pragma once` at the beginning on a header. This, although being supported by all major compilers, is not standardized way of protecting from double-including a header.

2) Add an *include guard*:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_GUARD
#define MY_HEADER_GUARD
    // your header contents go here
#endif
```

If you want to solve the ODR problem for functions and data variables, the above approach won't work because you can still have them defined multiple times in different `.cpp` files.
For this, you still have 2 options:

1) **define** your function somewhere outside, namely, in some `.cpp` file, only leaving its declaration in the header:

```
// header.h
namespace parser {
    void func();
}

// file.cpp
void parser::func() { ... }
```

2) Declare your function as *inline*, as inline function are allowed to have multiple definitions by the C++ standard (however, they must be strictly identical up to lexem level):

```
// header.h
namespace parser {
    inline void func() { ... }
}
```

To sum it up, I'd strongly recommend you go both directions by protecting your header from double inclusion **and** making sure your function is either inline or gets defined in a `.cpp` file. With the latter, if your function implementation changes, you won't have to recompile all the files that include your header, but only the one that has the functon definition.

Answer (score 0):

*Header files* ending with *.h*(usually) is often used to separate class and function declaration from their implementation.

In *Code::Blocks* you can add header files by right clicking on your project name **->** 'Add files' **->** create a new file with **.h** extension. Following good practise, you should also create a **.cpp** file with the same name where the implementation is written.

As already answered, in your *header file* you can first write an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) followed by your *include's* (if any) and also your function declarations. And in your *'parser.cpp'* & *'main.cpp'* you will have to `#include "parser.h"` since the files depend on eachother.